# Split json data in angular using regex

Tags: json, regex, angularjs, split

In every request of the service getting different formate of data. Below is my json data in different request.Is there any common regex pattern to split my data and get the expected result.

first req. json result:

```
"myid":"{1132} AND {1133} AND {1134} AND {1139} AND {1140} AND {1142} AND {1143} AND {1144} AND {1147} AND {1148} AND {1149} AND {1269} AND {1543} AND {1548} AND {1549} AND {1550} AND {1551} AND {1552} AND {1879} AND {1880} AND {1881} AND {1886} AND {1889} AND {1891} AND {1893} AND {1894}"
```

After split it should be :

```
1132----group 1 radio button
1132 ----group 2 radio button
1133 ----group 3 radio button
.
.
.
```

second req. Json Data :

```
"myid":"{1057} AND ({1131} OR {1132} OR {1133} OR {1134} OR {1139} OR {1140} OR {1550} OR {1551} OR {1552} OR {1879} OR {1880} OR {1881} OR {1147} OR {1148} OR {1149} OR {1269} OR {1548} OR {1549} OR {1141} OR {1142} OR {1143} OR {1144} OR {1145} OR {1146})"
```

After split it should be :

```
1057  ---group 1 radio button 
1131 ---group 2  radio button
1132  ---group 2 radio button
1133  ---group 2 radio button
.
.
```

third req. Json Data :

```
myid":"({1055} OR ({1056} AND {1057} AND {1058})) AND ({1131} OR {1132} OR {1133} OR {1134} OR {1139} OR {1140} OR {1550} OR {1551} OR {1552} OR {1879} OR {1880} OR {1881} OR {1147} OR {1148} OR {1149} OR {1269} OR {1548} OR {1549} OR {1141} OR {1142} OR {1143} OR {1144} OR {1145} OR {1146})"
```

After split it should be :

```
1055  ---group 1 radio button 
1056---group 2 check box
1057---group 2 check box
1058---group 2 check box
1131  ---group 3 radio button
1132  ---group 3  radio button
.
.
```

using below code breaking in two `$scope` variable (`$scope.mysplit`and `$scope.mysplitor`) and printing my result but due to dynamic behaviour of services data unable to generalize my logic.

```
$scope.mysplit = (val.myid).split("AND");
                    if ($scope.mysplit.length == 1) {
                        $scope.mysplitand = $scope.mysplit[0].substring(1, $scope.mysplit[0].length - 1);
                        $scope.mysplit = $scope.mysplitand;
                        $scope.mysplitor = [];
                    }
                    else {
                        $scope.mysplitand = $scope.mysplit[0].substring(1, $scope.mysplit[0].length - 2);
                        $scope.mysplitor = $scope.mysplit[1].substring(2, $scope.mysplit[1].length - 1).split("OR");
                        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.mysplitor.length; i++) {

                            $scope.mysplitor[i] = ($scope.mysplitor[i].trim());
                            $scope.mysplitor[i] = ($scope.mysplitor[i].substring(1, $scope.mysplit[0].length - 2));
                        }
                    }

                }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you clarify: on your first example, what's `11132`? On the third one, why are `1056` and `1057` separated in a check box? Generally speaking, what is the rule you use for splitting?

Comment: sorry typing mistake.Updated now